# Two versions of Postgres installed, how do I clean this up?

Tags: postgresql, update, migration

If I try to enable PostGIS with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` the error I see indicates that `psql` is looking for `postgres.control` in a 9.4 directory:

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

`postgis.control`  exists at `/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/postgis.control`

I don't have any need for two versions, and I don't know how I got myself into this situation. I'm on Ubuntu and just used synaptic to install I tried to migrate and got another affirmation that 9.5 is already installed:

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.4 main
Error: target cluster 9.5/main already exists
```

What is the Right Way™️ to switch over to using 9.5 so I can actually use PostGIS?

Comment: Did you uninstall 9.4?

Comment: Now I did, but that just shot all my databases and roles and gave me a bunch of new problems.